# MySql order by date asc, followed by user_id

Tags: mysql

what query should i make to achieved this outcome

here is my rows

```
user_id    | date
3          | 2017-09-07
2          | 2017-09-08
3          | 2017-09-10
```

and my desired output in query is this

```
user_id    | date
3          | 2017-09-07
3          | 2017-09-10
2          | 2017-09-08
```

but it's not based on user_id, i just want to query the rows **order by date ASC** and the user_id next to each other.

Comment: Do you have a query that you have tested ? You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Why do user's 2 records appear after user 3's records?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its not the whole table i just shown an example of rows to accommodate the question

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what you are asking.  You never answered my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He wants to order by the earliest-per-user `date`. I think the OP should add an *explicit* description of *this* requirement in his post.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I thought to post your exact answer but it would have been a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id
```

to get the earliest-per-user `date` value.

Using the above query as derived table you can achieve the required ordering:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.date
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS min_date
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
ORDER BY t2.min_date, user_id, t1.date
```

**Note:** In case two or more users share the same earliest date the query gives precedence to the user having the smallest `user_id` value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this solves my problem without asking why my rows like that :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you wan:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY user_id DESC, date ASC
```

Example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/899b0/2

Comment: @ImranAli Edited

Comment: as i said, i dont based it on user_id so this query wont work. my desired output is order by date ASC but also with user_id next to each other

Comment: I don't get the "next to each other" part, could you present the part of database architecture ?

Comment: look at the desired result (user_id) to understand next to each other part thanks

Comment: @ImranAli Actually you can use `order by` with the `*`, see example